# How do I create a numbered paragraph list in Github-Flavored Markdown?

Tags: syntax, format, github-flavored-markdown

Reading through GitHub's help website, I've come across a very neat-looking procedure list.

> [image]
>
> *From GitHub's [Create A Repo Tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)*

I have read through GitHub's [Markdown Tutorial](https://help.github.com/categories/writing-on-github/) as well as the [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet), but have not found any way to perfectly replicate this type of format.

The closest I have done so far was to basically put a blockquote after a number list entry:

```
 1. > line 1
    >
    > line 2

 2. > line 3
    >
    > line 4
```

And it looks similar, but, well, see for yourself:

> [image]

- **Is this the closest I can get to GitHub's format?**
- **Is there a proper Markdown syntax that I have missed?**
- **If not, is there a way to achieve this in raw HTML?**

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of that page you can see that this is just a normal ordered list containing paragraphs:

```html
<ol>
<li><p>In the upper-right corner of any page, click...
```

So to produce that HTML with markdown simply use the normal ordered list syntax:

```
1. First paragraph here.

2. Another paragraph here.
```

The particular appearance of that page is done by styling with CSS. It looks a little involved, using the `::before` pseudo-element. If you want to replicate something similar have a look at the page with your browsers inspector to see the the styles. Experiment until you understand how it works and can create the effect you want.

If you are looking to create this effect on your own Github pages (e.g. a README) then I think you are out of luck, since you can’t control the CSS.